# How to debug a Symfony StreamedResponse?

Tags: php, symfony, stream, response

I'm using a `StreamedResponse` to serve a large CSV file. When I get an error in the *callback function*, the browser merely displays a "file not found" error, and I have no access to the Symfony debug toolbar. Is there a way to access the Exception that was thrown in the callback ?
My action looks like this:

```
  public function exportAction(Request $request) {

     $response = new StreamedResponse();
     $response->setCallback(function() {

        // Here i'm fetching my data with Doctrine and outputting it with 
        // $handle = fopen('php://output', 'w'); ...fputcsv() ...fclose();

     });

     $response->setStatusCode(200);
     $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/csv; charset=utf-8');
     $response->headers->set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment; filename="export.csv"');

     return $response;
  }
```

**EDIT**
Most of the time, when looking at the request in the browser dev tool, the response content is blank.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... I don't know of any convenient method, but you could load the homepage, open the profiler, and click the "Last 10" button to see past profiles.

Comment: Thanks, there might be a more convenient way but that did the trick.

Comment: Sometimes, when looking in the browser dev tool console, I don't even get a status for the failing request and it doesn't appear in the "last 10" button. Any idea why ? Only getting "file not found" message.

Answer (score 1):

> **Caution**
>
> The web debug toolbar is not available for responses of type
> `StreamedResponse`.

Source: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/web_profiler.html